# After Upgrate Magento 2 from version 2.2.5 to 2.3.4 Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: magento2.3, database, error, magento-upgrade, foreign-key-constraint

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2 version from 2.2.5 to 2.3.4 using CLI.
Version up-gradation is done. After version upgrade when I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it will give an error as follow:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wheels_financing_live`.`#sql-4a3_9e8`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` MODIFY COLUMN `value` decimal(20, 6)  NULL  COMMENT "Value", ADD CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE

Here **wheels_financing_live** is my DB name.
[image: magento]